# Spark - from_avro function returning null values

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read the contents of names.json file. Below is the content. And encoding it to avro format using `to_avro` method and decoding it back to normal text using `from_avro` method.

```
{"name":"alex"}
{"name":"bart"}
{"name":"tamir"}
{"name":"brandon"}
{"name":"zach"}
```

When I decode the avro data, the resulting dataframe bringing in null values instead of the actual data. below is the code.

```
val jsonData = spark.read.json("pathto/names.json")

jsonData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [rawdata: string]

jsonData.show(truncate=false)

+----------------------------+
|name                        |
+----------------------------+
|alex                        |
|bart                        |
|tamir                       |
|brandon                     |
|zach                        |
+----------------------------+

val res = jsonData.select(to_avro($"name") as 'value)

val schema_struct="""
{"namespace": "com.names.data",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
"""

val ans = res.select(from_avro('value, schema_struct) as 'user)

ans.show()

Output result
+----+
|name|
+----+
|  []|
|  []|
|  []|
|  []|
|  []|
|  []|
|  []|
+----+
```

Not sure why I'm gettign null values, though I have correct data type. Am I doing something incorrect here? I tried the equivalent code using pyspark and getting same results. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Do you remember what was the issue?

Comment: I couldnt solve it. Rather using the spark provided function, I built my own encoder and decoder function using avro library. That solved the problem

Comment: Had this issue b/c the from_avro function assumes normal avro format, whereas the avro records I was targeting to parse were in confluent wire format (magic byte + schema ID in first 5 bytes). Manually manipulating the binary data to remove those bytes before passing to from_avro did the trick for me